# TypeError: Parameter 'metadata' received Metadata as an argument, which is incompatible with parameter type: MetadataColumn[Categorical]

Tags: python, bioinformatics, qiime

TypeError: Parameter 'metadata' received Metadata as an argument, which is incompatible with parameter type: MetadataColumn[Categorical]

for the following code:

```
uUniFrac_BodySite_significance = diversity.actions.beta_group_significance(core_metrics.unweighted_unifrac_distance_matrix, sample_metadata)

uUniFrac_BodySite_significance.visualization
```

Visualized my table with:

```
!metadata.actions.tabulate? #runs help function in the terminal
tabulate = metadata.actions.tabulate(sample_metadata)
tabulate.visualization #displays metadata table and whether column's numeric or categorical
```

Answer (score -1):

#.get_column('name_of_column_w_categorical_type'))

uUniFrac_Subject_significance = diversity.actions.beta_group_significance(core_metrics.unweighted_unifrac_distance_matrix, **sample_metadata.get_column('name_of_column_w_categorical_type')**)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).